# Подсчитать количество уникальных чисел в каждой строке

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть матрица:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=100).reshape(10,10))
df
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   9   1   7   0   5   0   1   9   7   4
1   5   8   5   5   8   1   6   2   6   1
2   5   2   6   0   0   9   3   3   0   1
3   0   5   3   0   1   6   3   1   4   9
4   6   1   2   0   8   3   4   7   6   2
5   7   0   1   3   1   1   7   9   4   1
6   7   4   1   5   7   5   9   6   0   8
7   0   0   6   5   0   3   8   2   7   3
8   2   8   7   8   8   8   3   3   5   3
9   5   5   7   7   0   6   3   0   6   7
```

Нужно добавить столбец - количество уникальных чисел в строке.
Хочу получить :

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 counts
0   9   1   7   0   5   0   1   9   7   4    6
1   5   8   5   5   8   1   6   2   6   1    5
2   5   2   6   0   0   9   3   3   0   1    7
3   0   5   3   0   1   6   3   1   4   9    7
4   6   1   2   0   8   3   4   7   6   2    8
5   7   0   1   3   1   1   7   9   4   1    6
6   7   4   1   5   7   5   9   6   0   8    8
7   0   0   6   5   0   3   8   2   7   3    7
8   2   8   7   8   8   8   3   3   5   3    5
9   5   5   7   7   0   6   3   0   6   7    5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.nunique(axis=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html):

```
df["counts"] = df.nunique(axis=1)
```

Результат:

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  counts
0  9  1  7  0  5  0  1  9  7  4       6
1  5  8  5  5  8  1  6  2  6  1       5
2  5  2  6  0  0  9  3  3  0  1       7
3  0  5  3  0  1  6  3  1  4  9       7
4  6  1  2  0  8  3  4  7  6  2       8
5  7  0  1  3  1  1  7  9  4  1       6
6  7  4  1  5  7  5  9  6  0  8       8
7  0  0  6  5  0  3  8  2  7  3       7
8  2  8  7  8  8  8  3  3  5  3       5
9  5  5  7  7  0  6  3  0  6  7       5
```

Comment: это promt? удобный вывод, и почему именно он кстати?